# Extract Location from Response Header with JMeter

Tags: string, bash, jmeter, http-headers

I have this string :

```
Location →/cochise/workflow/5c46e69364ddf300013412b5
```

How do I extract the final hexadecimal code using jmeter?

Answer (score 8):

Add a `Regular Expression Extractor` post processor as a child of your request with below configurations:

- Apply to: `Main sample and sub-samples`
- Field to check: `Response Headers`
- Reference Name: `myVar`
- Regular Expression: `Location: .+\/(.*?)\n`
- Template: `$1$`
- Match No: `1`
- Default Value: `NOT_FOUND`

Now you can use jmeter variable `${myVar}` which contains hexadecimal value. You can add view results tree and debug sampler at thread group level to make sure you are extracting the right value.

References

- [Regular expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) from Jmeter user manual.
- [Using regex with jmeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is going for the [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

1. Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the request which returns the above header
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]

   for your convenience here is the textual form of the regular expression:

   ```
   /cochise/workflow/(.*)
   ```
3. That's it, you should now be able to access the extracted value as `${foo}` where required.
4. Also be aware that you can test your regular expressions via `RegExp Tester` mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. This approach in conjunction with i.e. [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) can greatly speed up scripts development process as you will not have to re-run the entire scenario in order to test an extractor:

   [image]