# Extract location from response header in Jmeter

Tags: regex, string, jmeter

From the below string

https://ABC.somewebsitename.com/Account/AutoLogOn?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMDEyMzk3ODMiLCJ0YXJnZXRDb3VudHJ5Q29kZSI6IkpQIiwiZXhwIjoiMTU3OTUxMjc4MiJ9.QhfDKvZXSrqTjGYsBaZUd6ErbYoOJUdta0efws2SI-nv0VYqUvByHvoKbWVGvd89RmOi-KV33CDHU8NE_Pl0NA

I want to extract the value after token and send it as a parameter in next request for that I used Regular Expression extractor as below

[image]

But in the next request parameter, I am not able to get those values 

[image]

Am I missing something, can you help me on this?

Note: I have followed the link [Extract Location from Response Header with JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305507/extract-location-from-response-header-with-jmeter) but still no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some trial and error, and got the answer, 
In the Regular Expression Extractor, used as

- Regular Expression: `Location: .+\/AutoLogOn\?token=(.*?)\n`

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is missing [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), I believe you should amend it like:

```
https.+token=(.*)
```

Demo:

[image]

However if you just need to extract the token and append it to the next request it is easier to consider [Using the HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-http-url-re-writing-modifier/)

Comment: Hello @Dmitri T, I have updated my reg expression as you suggested but it is giving the same message as before in the next request.                                                           
 GET https://ABC.somewebsitename.com/Account/AutoLogOn?token=C_token_login_NF

Comment: @Rajashekar Can you try with token=(.+?)$? It should work

Comment: Then your regular expression extractor fails, try playing with "Apply to" and "Field to check" parameters, unfortunately we cannot come up with the proper configuration without seeing where this URL is coming from. See [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Regular expression should be **token=(.+?)$**

Also set the **Field to Check** to **URL** in the Regular Expression Extractor element.